# R Function that parse text file and extract a specific value

Tags: r, git, csv, text

I have two files: csv file & text file. in the csv file, i have commmit ID only, whereas in the text file, i have commit log which include commit ID and its related information.

I need to write a function in R that do the following:

1. Read the two files.
2. For each commit ID in csv, find that ID in
   the text file, parse the text after the ID, and get the number after
   "'" and before the space " "  (which is 4 in the example above).
3. Save the extracted number in a new column in csv file.

Code

```
birt =read.csv("C:/path/Obirt.csv", header =T)
cvs = data.frame(CID = C(birt$commitID)
txt = readLines("C:/path/summary.txt")
tail(unlist(strsplit(txt,"'")), 2)
tmp = data.frame(t(sapply(txt, function(x) c(unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(x, "'"))[2], ';')), tail(unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(x, "'"))[3], '  ')), 2)), USE.NAMES = F)))
colnames(tmp) = c('CID', 'COMMIT_NAME', 'COMMIT_TIME', 'COMMIT_SUB', 'NUM1', 'NUM2')
newcsv = merge(cvs, tmp, by='CID')
write.csv(newcsv, 'C:/Users/abdul/desktop/umbc/birt/newcsv.csv', row.names = F)
```

However, it is unable to merge the data.

The text file format is 'commit ID; commiter name; commit time; description' whereas some records include additional info 'commit ID; commiter name; commit time; description' num num  patch file (like commit ID ba37902179 below).

Example: 
'99e88cb4c9;Yulin Wang;Mon Sep 11 08:43:32 2017 -0700;Merge pull request #418 from ZwoCa/master'
'9be3838165;Sebastian;Mon Sep 11 15:06:07 2017 +0200;Merge pull request #1 from ZwoCa/ZwoCa-patch-1'
'ba37902179;Sebastian;Mon Sep 11 15:00:33 2017 +0200;Fixed inverted assertion'
1   1   data/org.eclipse.birt.data/src/org/eclipse/birt/data/engine/executor/transform/SimpleResultSet.java'f6d86d5f95;Gary Xue;Mon Aug 28 20:51:37 2017 -0400;Merge pull request #417 from Bharadwaj14/master'
'95acb82708;Gary Xue;Mon Aug 28 20:50:29 2017 -0400;Merge pull request #416 from rrimmana/master'
'3ff8e99b70;Bharadwaj Tirunagaru;Mon Aug 28 15:18:13 2017 +0530;removing 3289.patch'
0   102 3289.patch'1dbc5116ae;rrimmana;Mon Aug 28 15:06:13 2017 +0530;A report that based on Mongo ODA driver with Kerberos authentication turned off where connection to Mongo DB, using ODA driver is throwing NPE. Its a backward compatibility bug.'
2   5 data/org.eclipse.birt.data.oda.mongodb/src/org/eclipse/birt/data/oda/mongodb/impl/MongoDBDriver.java'

based on the example, i think the solution would be something like

```
tmp = data.frame(t(sapply(txt, function(x)unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(x, "'"))[2], ';')))))
   if (//there is Not"''" at the end of a tail//) // i am not sure how to make 
                                                       such condition
   Then tmp = c(tail(unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(x, "'"))[3], '  ')), 2), 
                USE.NAMES = F)
```

Comment: Please review [mcve] and show the code for what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This code will parse the data that you provided and merge the elements with a matching commit ID in a separate data frame and then write the new data frame out as a CSV. The two commented lines are what you would use for your actual data. It is highly dependent on the format being the way you specified in your question so if there are any deviations in the log files it will not parse the lines correctly. Also the column name `CID` will need to be changed to match whatever it really is in your CSV file.

```r
csv = data.frame(CID = c('A1234', 'B1234', 'C1234'))
#csv = read.csv('csvfile.csv')
txt = c("'A1234;commmiter name;commmit time;commmit subject' 4 1","'B1234;commmiter name;commmit time;commmit subject' 5 1","'C1234;commmiter name;commmit time;commmit subject' 6 1")
#txt = readLines('textfile.txt')
tail(unlist(strsplit(txt, "'")), 2)
tmp = data.frame(t(sapply(txt, function(x) c(unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(x, "'"))[2], ';')), tail(unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(x, "'"))[3], ' ')), 2)), USE.NAMES = F)))
colnames(tmp) = c('CID', 'COMMIT_NAME', 'COMMIT_TIME', 'COMMIT_SUB', 'NUM1', 'NUM2')

newcsv = merge(csv, tmp, by='CID')
write.csv(newcsv, 'newcsv.csv', row.names = F)
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob. i tried the code above; it does very well text split, but cannot merge the two files.

Comment: Does it give you an error, or does it give you a data frame with zero rows when you merge the two? Without some better examples of the data you are working with in both files it is hard to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: It give data with zero rows, only show the headings.   he csv file contains only one column (CID).  the text file looks like the example above.  Note that not all row begin and end with '.  some rows include number of changes after ' in addition to patch file, and some not

Comment: any thought Jacob?  text file looks like   'CID;name;time;subject'        sometime there is  Num1   Num2    URL    after  'CID;name;time;subject'  and sometimes not.  I think IF statement would be used (but i'm not sure how to implement it). For example, after including 'CID;name;time;subject'  in a tail, an IF condition that check if the character after the tail is " ' ", that's mean NA (no Num exist for this case). and IF the character is Num Then extract this number. 
The merged csv file will include the column (CID, name, time, subject, Num)

Answer (score 0):

By observing the format in the text file, i think the unlist(strsplit) function should be something like

```
tmp = data.frame(t(sapply(txt, function(x)unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(x, "'"))[2], ';')))))
   if (//there is Not"''" at the end of a record//) // i am not sure how to make 
                                                       such condition
   Then tmp = c(tail(unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(x, "'"))[3], '  ')), 2), 
                USE.NAMES = F)
```

because not all tail has the two numbers after. but i am not sure how to formulate the IF condition above.